# negative palindrome number failure

Tags: c++, boolean

i need to determine if a number is palindrome or not
ex: 121 yes,
ex: -121 no.
the program seems to work with palindrome numbers however i am having trouble figuring out the negative numbers, and non palindrome numbers

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(int x) {
        int reverse = 0;
        int digit;
        int n = x;
        bool t = true;
         while(x > 0){
             digit = x%10;
             reverse = (reverse*10) + digit;
             x = x/10;  
         }
        if (n == reverse) {
         return t;
        } 
        else if(n != reverse) {
            return -1;
        }
    return -1;
         
    }
};
```

Comment: Are any negative number palindromes? Why can't you just add `if (x < 0) return false;`?

Comment: `return -1;` is incorrect as `-1` will be converted to true when the integer is converted to a boolean. Presumably you meant `return false;`.

Comment: The last seven lines of your code could be simplified to one line `return n == reverse;`. Which means 'if n equals reverse then return true otherwise return false'. Which is what you are trying to say I think. Beginners often struggle with booleans and write code that is more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: You don't need to use `else if` when the second condition is the opposite of the first condition. Just use `else`

Comment: i got it thank you!

Comment: @Barmar seeing that `else if()` returns the same value as at the bottom of the function, you don't need `else` at all

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isPalindrome(int A)
{
int Rev{ 0 } , rem , C{ A };

while( ( abs( A ) ) ! = 0 )
{
rem = ( abs( A ) ) % 10;
Rev = Rev * 10 + rem;
A / = 10;
}

if( C ! = Rev or C < 0)
 return false;

else if( C == Rev and C > 0)
 return true;
}
```

Change your if statements with the following and then this works for negative numbers.

Hope this works for you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
  public boolean isPalindrome(int x){
    int reverse=0;
  int duplicate_x=x;
    for(int i=0;i<=x;i++)
       {
      int r=x%10;
      reverse=(reverse*10)+r;
      x=x/10;
        }
        if(x>=1){       **wrote this if condition to catch  unit place number**
         reverse=(reverse*10)+x;
        }
         if(reverse==duplicate_x)
            {
              return true;
             }
            else
            {
           return false; 
            }
          }
}
```

I used for loop because I was getting time exceeding error in leetcode
and has you mention in your question about negative number palindrome I don't get it why should we write code for those negative number palindrome where we know a **negative number cannot be a palindrome number!
Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You can't safely reverse an `int` value like that. Consider `INT_MAX`. Or anything over 2,000,000,000 that ends with any digit over 2.

Comment: @VladFeinstein yes I just check.. I'm getting an answer like -1126087180 for INT_MAX can you please tell me how to improve this code...and the reason why I'm getting output like that..Where my code works perfectly fine if the number is below INT_MAX..

Comment: If you must stay with integer - just use 64-bit values for intermediate storage. But I would simply store all digits in the vector and then walk from both ends to the middle to check for pallindrom (like you would do with a string). Oh, and the reason is - the max int value you can store is 2,147,483,647 so none of the 10-digit values that start with 3+ will fit.

Comment: Ohh tysm!! Although they already mention Constraints as such in leetcode: (-2^31 <= x <= 2^31 - 1) but haven't paid attention

Answer (score 0):

```
int x=121;
    if(x<0){
        System.out.println("false");
        System.exit(0); 
    }
    int div, sum=0;
    int res=x;
    while(x!=0){
        div = x%10;
        sum = sum*10 + div;
        x=x/10;
    }
    if(sum==res)
        System.out.println("True");
```

Can't be able to come up with a simple solution more than this one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).